# React-Navigation requireNativeComponent: "RNSScreenStackHeaderConfig" was not found in the UIManager

Tags: react-native, runtime-error, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

=> MacOS Monterey Version 12.6.2

=> Xcode Version 14.2

Bellow is my package version:-

```
"@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.17.11",
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.2",
"@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.8",
"react": "18.1.0",
"react-native": "0.70.6",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.4.1",
"react-native-screens": "^3.18.2"
```

Hear is my Navigation File code:-

```
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import * as React from 'react';
import ScreenManager from './Screens/ScreenManager';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

export default MyStack = () => {
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Stack.Navigator
                screenOptions={{
                    headerShown: false
                }}
            >
                <Stack.Screen
                    name="Home"
                    component={ScreenManager}
                />
           </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
};
```

Showing this error in Simulator

[image]

i am install react navigation dependency from follow bellow url =>
https://reactnative.dev/docs/navigation

and also try pod install command. but still getting fail to run my application.